# Nullity of the same matrix over a finite and infinite field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Is there a relation between the nullity of the same matrix over a finite field and a infinite field?

Or is there a prime power q so there the differents of nullity of a matrix over, let's say the rational numbers and the field $\Bbb{F_q}$ is small?

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes most sense if you ask it about a matrix of integers, say $A$. It is slightly easier to talk about the rank, so I will do that: the Rank-Nullity Theorem lets one translate to nullities.

Given such a matrix matrix $A$ we can find (by the Smith Normal Form algorithm) invertible matrices of integers $P,Q$ of determinant $\pm 1$ such that $PAQ=D$ where 
$$
D=\begin{pmatrix} 
d_1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & d_2 & \dots & 0 & \dots& 0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots & 0 &\dots& 0\\
0 & 0 &\dots& d_k & \dots &0\\
\vdots &\vdots& & \vdots& & \vdots\\
0 & 0 &&0&&0
\end{pmatrix} \text{ (all other entries $0$)}
$$
with non-zero integers $d_1|d_2|\dots|d_k$.

If now $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$, the rank of $A$ is $k$.

If $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$ then the rank of $A$ is $\ell$ where $\ell$ is the least $s$ such that $p\not|d_s$.

Comment: And what's the case if the matrix entries are all $1,...p$ ? What i mean is to start in $/Bbb{F_p}$  and then i want something to say about the nullity in the rationals...

Comment: There is no unique - even no sensible? - way to transform a matrix over $\mathbb{F}_p$ into a rational matrix. If you specify how you are to turn your matrix into an integer matrix my answer will tell you what happens.

Comment: What i mean is: you look at a matrix in $ \Bbb{F_p}$  und you take simply the numbers in $\Bbb{F_p}$  and look at them as normal integers

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ are not natural numbers. The number $0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ corresponds to any of the integers $0,\pm p,\pm 2p, \dots$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a prime; then the nullity of
\begin{bmatrix}
p & 2p \\
p & 3p
\end{bmatrix}
is zero over $\mathbb{Q}$ (and every infinite field of characteristic $0$); on the other hand, the matrix has nullity two over the $p$-element field (and every extension thereof).

If $K$ is an extension of the field $F$, then the rank and nullity of a matrix over $F$ don't change if we consider it as a matrix over $K$, because the rank can be computed with Gaussian elimination and is the same over $F$ and over $K$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Right: I was thinking to characteristic zero, but it remained in the keyboard.

Comment: Does it chance if i have a diluted large matrix?